# convert an array of array .. json in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, json

given an apparently invalid json 
(which comes from google)

https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=en&tl=de&dt=t&q=Science

of

```
[[["Wissenschaft","Science",,,2]],,"en"]
```

i want to get the values of Wissenschaft and Science

if figured out a very inelegant way to do it with Json.net via

```
string h = "[[[\"Wissenschaft\",\"Science\",,,2]],,\"en\"] ";
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<dynamic>>(h);
JArray arr1 = obj[0];
var arr2 = arr1.First;
var x = arr2.First.Next;
string s = x.ToString();
```

is there some better, less verbose way ?

Comment: This is a json which is returned by `var res = hc.GetAsync("https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=en&tl=ge&dt=t&q=Science").Result; ` So i cannot influence the json. Also Json.Net parses it without problems.

Comment: I have no idea what your request returns. but @CodeCaster has right... This is not valid JSON ...

Comment: Well thats too bad :-(  i cannot change the json (coming from google) and json.net is happily parsing it regardless. So is there a better way to get the values ? If not then maybe this Q helps someone else with equally "broken" json.

Comment: @CodeCaster : as i wrote Json.Net has already parsed and accepted the invalid json, so i am not looking for correctness. I would like to write some less verbose code. Do you have anything to contribute to that question ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more concise version, maybe somebody has one which also retains 
the other values from the top array

```
string h = "[[[\"Wissenschaft\",\"Science\",,,2]],,\"en\"]";
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
    settings.Error = (serializer, err) =>
    {
        err.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
        //ignore all errors   
    };
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<List<dynamic>>>>(h,settings);
string strWissenschaft = obj[0][0][0];
string strScience = obj[0][0][1];
```

As you see i only care for the values in the most nested array, the other values are lost.

Answer (score 0):

For first this is not valid JSON object but nevermind as you said [Json.NET](http://Json.NET%20-%20Newtonsoft) will parse it by adding null values into empty commas.

Because this is not valid object and it is just an array in some JSON format. There will probably no better way then parse it into dynamic List as you already did.

In case of `{  }` at start and end and some keys:values format you can deserialize it into C# object according to class which you can define.